# Display MemberPath instead of Value in WPF DataGrid

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have two SQL tables

In table 1 every row have value(string) in System Code column

In table 2 every row have value(int) in Device column which is ID of related Table 1 row.

Now i want to display Table 2 in WPF DataGrid and in Device Column value of System Code from Table 1. Now it's displaying ID of Table 1 row.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create new class for the itmes, where you can store all needed properties. In your case it will be the projection of the join.

DataGrid's `DisplayMemberPath` relates only to the corresponding item. If data item which stands for representation of table's row allows naviagation to the property `SystemCode` of the Table1 then it is ok.